# Arthimatic Quiz Not Accepting Correct Answers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I am attempting to make an arithmetic quiz, but have run into this issue: Even if I input the correct answer, it seems to ignore the correct answer code and go straight to the incorrect answer code. Basically, it doesn't accept any right answers.

```
import random
num1 = (random.randrange(10))
num2 = (random.randrange(10))
correct1 = (num1*num2)

ans1 = input("What is " + str(num1) + " multiplied by " + str(num2) + "? ")

if ans1 == correct1:
    print("Correct! ")

if ans1 != correct1:
    print(" Incorrect. ")
    print("  The correct answer was " + str(ans1))
```

When ran, I get something like this:

```
What is 3 multiplied by 0? 0
    Incorrect. 
        The correct answer was 0
```

Note how the answer and my input were the same, but it ran the code for an incorrect answer. Can anyone help me to fix this? I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: Because `'0' != 0` - `input` gives you *a string*.

Comment: Don't put *"answered"* in the question, accepting an answer marks this as answered.

Comment: also do notice that you are printing the user's input as the "correct answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3` is not equal to `"3"`. The result of a call to `input` (in Python3) is a string, not a number.

Call `int` on the user input

```
...

ans1 = input("What is " + str(num1) + " multiplied by " + str(num2) + "? ")
ans1 = int(ans1)

...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if int(ans1) == correct1:
    print("Correct! ")
else:
    print(" Incorrect. ")
    print("  The correct answer was " + str(ans1))
```

You must compare numbers with numbers.
You were comparing '3' vs 3