# Python IDLE : how to run the whole script as it is always stopping at some point

Tags: python, python-idle

I created a list, and I offered the user the ability to choose whichever method he would like to run. However when the user selects a number, the if else statements are not being executed. Does anyone know why is that ? I am new to IDLE and python.

this is my code

```
aList = ['hello','bonjour','hola','ohayo','hello'];
print("our list is: ", aList)

print("1-count, 2-inList, 3-Reverse, 4-find, 5-insert")
choice = input("please call the function you want to execute: ")

if choice == 1:
    word = input("which word would you like to count? ")
    print(aList.count(word))
elif choice == 2:
    inList = input("which word would you like to check if it's in the list")
    if inList in aList:
        print(True)
    else :
        print(False)
elif choice == 3:
    for i in reversed(aList):
        print(i)
elif choice == 4:
    item = input("what item would you like to find?")
    aList.index(item)
elif choice == 5:
    item = input("what would you like to anwser? ")
    aList.insert(item)
```

and this is the output

> our list is:  ['hello', 'bonjour', 'hola', 'ohayo', 'hello']
>   1-count, 2-inList, 3-Reverse, 4-find, 5-insert please call the
>   function you want to execute: 1
>
> > > >

always stopping after I put the number. I am obviously not understanding python well

Comment: Because `'1' != 1`... See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28457422/3001761 or any one of tens of thousands of other similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast to an integer:

```
choice = int(input("please call the function you want to execute: "))
```